# Require function path

Tags: lua, require

*Hello,*

I was trying to require a file trough command prompt, which the path is "C:\Source\File.lua", but it isn't working, and I can't find a solution anywhere.

I tried this:

```lua
require("..\\..\\Source\\File")
```

This:

```lua
require([[..\..\Source\File]])
```

And this:

```lua
require([[..\..\Source\File.lua]])
```

None of them worked, they say it couldn't find the file, but if I move it, for example, to desktop, it works fine.

*Thank you.*

Comment: Does `dofile([[..\..\Source\File.lua]])` work?

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Hello

> For require the Lua interpreter uses package.path. And when you add the path to your require in the right manner you dont need the .lua suffix for require().

---

Example extending package path in lua console

```
 # cp koys.lua /tmp/
 # lua5.3 
Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> package.path=package.path..';/tmp/?.lua'
> koys=require('koys')
> koys
table: 0x565a7120
```

Comment: What the `package.path=package.path..';/tmp/?.lua'` do in that case?

Comment: Also, I tested it, and it didn't worked. Sorry for the late comment.

Comment: Look what is in your package.path and put your File.lua in one of that places.```print(package.path)``` My example is using a path syntax for a linux system. I guess you have to do that in ms-dos syntax.

Comment: ```;/tmp/?.lua``` - In this case the require() accepts files from /tmp/  folder with extension .lua so this part ( .lua ) is not required for finding File. Or: ? is a placeholder for File

Comment: And i think it is important to know that the two dots ```..``` as used in my example put two strings together to one. Like: ```"Hello ".."World"``` So package.path becomes old path plus new path and not only new path

Comment: Oh, now I understand, thank you! So the `package.path=package.path..';/tmp/?.lua'` basically "moves" the require function to the folder, so I can execute it in the folder?

Comment: Yes - The point is package.path is the map require() look at when it search for File. So "moves" is simply the information require() needs to see on map.

Comment: Another nice feature of require() vs. doload() is that you can see whats loaded in package.loaded. And with the package.path extension you can change the rule for the allowed extensions. Example: ```';/tmp/?.inc'``` This allows only .inc files to be loaded from /tmp/